Is there a term for verbs that only go with one noun?
For example, only clouds scud, only cattle low.

"From the thick copse the roebucks bound, The startled red-deer scuds the plain" - Walter Scott

Scud can definitely be used with other nouns (indeed, of the two example sentences given in the Oxford Dictionary of English as used in the macOS Dictionary app, one is about ships rather than clouds), so not the best example – but the notion itself is valid enough. I’m not familiar with a term for it, though. It’s not the same as cranberry morphemes (since these are words, not morphemes); and also not the same as fossil words (since they’re not necessarily fossilised in any way).
